# Can the A'dam bracelet be modified to work with other bracelets to make linking easier for Aes Sedai?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I'm currently on book 6 of *Wheel of Time* series, "Lord of Chaos". In it, Elayne has crafted a modified A'dam after realizing that the bracelet doesn't need to be leashed to the necklace. They've come to realize that this is similar to the linking that Aes Sedai do, with one being in control. In the times I've seen it, the linking of Aes Sedai is something that takes at least a minimal effort to be open to it.

So the question is, can the bracelets be modified in such a way that two Aes Sedai wearing them link without having to go through the effort of linking?

Comment: Maybe, for once, they stopped to think if they should, instead of being more preoccupied whether or not they could...

Comment: @Nae'blis What you did there, I see it.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, this is possible.

As a matter of fact, the *a'dam* is in fact merely forming a link between the wearers.

From *Lord of Chaos*, Prologue:

> Bracelet and necklace created a link between them, much in the way Aes Sedai could link to combine their power.

Or, from the Glossary in the same:

> ***a'dam*** (AYE-dam): A device for controlling a woman who can channel...It creates a link between the two women...

Elayne and Nynaeve are also worried about joining a circle while wearing the *a'dam* (spoilered for people who haven't gotten to *Lord of Chaos* yet):

> What might have happened had Elayne entered the link already linked to Moghedien by the *a'dam*?

Answer (score 0):

Can this magic do this is somewhat subjective if we have not been explicitly shown

With that being said the answer come down to probably yes it could

However the effort to create a ter'angreal to do this is probably much more than the effort required to link in the first place